# How to know if a user is connected to cellular network or wifi using reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is there any way or package which I can use to detect to whether user is on WiFi or using cellular network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to try

```
const networkInformation = navigator.connection;
console.log(networkInformation);
```

For more info try https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/connection

Worth looking at [Determine user's internet connection type via javascript or jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23772390/determine-users-internet-connection-type-via-javascript-or-jquery) as well.

Comment: So seems like there is no way to test this in production